# TypeScript error: Conversion of type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' to type 'K' may be a mistake

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a TypeScript function that takes an object and an array of properties to ignore, and returns the object without those properties. Here's my function:

```js
interface Obj {
  [key: string]: any;
}

function transpose<T extends Obj, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ignore: K[]): Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> {
  const result: Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> = {} as Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
  for (const prop in obj) {
    if (!ignore.includes(prop as K)) {
      result[obj[prop]] = prop as Exclude<keyof T, K>;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

It works however typescript gives me the following errors

```bash
Conversion of type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' to type 'K' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  'Extract<keyof T, string>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
    Type 'string & keyof T' is not comparable to type 'K'.
      'string & keyof T' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
        Type 'string' is not comparable to type 'K'.
          'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
Type 'Exclude<keyof T, K>' is not assignable to type 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]'.
  'Exclude<keyof T, K>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]', but 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any'.
    Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]'.
      'keyof T' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]', but 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any'.
        Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]'.
          'string | number | symbol' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]', but 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any'.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]'.
              'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]', but 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any'.
                Type 'Exclude<string, K> | Exclude<number, K> | Exclude<symbol, K>' is not assignable to type 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]'.
                  'Exclude<string, K> | Exclude<number, K> | Exclude<symbol, K>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]', but 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any'.
                    Type 'Exclude<string, K>' is not assignable to type 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]'.
                      'Exclude<string, K>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]', but 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any'.
                        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]'.
                          'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]', but 'T[T[Extract<keyof T, string>]]' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'any'.
Conversion of type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' to type 'Exclude<keyof T, K>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'string & keyof T' is not comparable to type 'Exclude<keyof T, K>'.
```

I wrote a TypeScript function that takes an object and an array of property keys to be ignored, but when I tried to add a new key that is not part of the object to the ignore array, TypeScript showed an error with the message:

"Conversion of type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' to type 'K' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first."

I expected the TypeScript compiler to accept my code and add the new key to the ignore array. However, I got this error instead, and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: In order for your code to be a good [mre] it shouldn't have any extraneous or complicating issues that you're not trying to ask about.  Please [edit] to clear the following issues up: • The `Obj` type is unnecessary and can be replaced with `object`. • The type `Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>` should be replaced with the equivalent but more ergonomic and common `Omit<T, K>` ...

Comment: ... • The function presumably swaps keys and values (hence the name and the implementation) but the return type is wrong; it isn't even close to `Omit<T, K>`; please either give it the right typings or change your function to actually return `Omit<T, K>`.  || See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mA8YXN) and consider replacing the code in your question with that version.